# multiple permission at same time with proper validation in flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions

**Permission**

- Camera
- storage
- location

request all three permission
if any one permission denied then re ask

after two time ask and denied by user then , third time open app settings

and if granted all three permission then navigate screen

**tried it**

```
    void goToHome(context) async {
Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> status = await [
  Permission.camera,
  Permission.location,
  Permission.storage,

].request();

if (status.toString().contains('${status.toString()}')) {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await preferences.setInt('isBoarding', 0);
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeScreen()),
  );
  print('+++++++++++${status.toString()}');
}
if (status == PermissionStatus.denied) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('data')));
}
if (status.toString().contains('PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied') ||
    status.toString().contains('PermissionStatus.restricted')) {
  openAppSettings();
}
```

**problem**

navigate screen even if permission is denied

**simply understanding**

*want to like this*
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krUs4.gif)

*my tried output*
[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdWqK.gif)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

replace first condition with :

```
if (status.toString().contains('PermissionStatus.granted')) {
   SharedPreferences preferences = await 
   SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   await preferences.setInt('isBoarding', 0);
   Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeScreen()),
   );
   print('+++++++++++${status.toString()}');
}
```

Comment: same issue of Navigation with denied permission\